# problem with string.format, \directlua and tex.sprint

Tags: luatex

I wonder if someone could explain to me why

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
the standard approximation $\pi = \directlua{tex.sprint(math.pi)}$
\end{document}
```

works all right, whereas

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
the standard approximation $\pi = \directlua{tex.sprint(string.format(' %.3f', math.pi))}$
\end{document}
```

throws an `Undefined control sequence. \end{document}`

It is probably something very basic, but I just don't get it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `%` (percent) symbol is special to both (La)TeX and Lua, but in very different ways. In (La)TeX, it's the default comment character. In Lua, it's one of the "magic" characters in pattern matching operations. (Lua's other "magic" characters are `^$().[]*+-?`.)

The `\directlua` directive is *expandable*, in the TeX-specific sense of the word. This means that TeX scans the argument of `\directlua` for any macros; if macros are found, TeX will try to expand them. In your second example, when (La)TeX scans

```
\directlua{tex.sprint(string.format(' %.3f', math.pi))}
```

it doesn't come across any LaTeX macros, but it does encounter the `%` character, which it interprets as a comment character. Hence, everything through the end of the input line is ignored, including the two closing parentheses and the single closing curly brace. That's why you're getting an error message.

---

How to keep these two, rather incompatible, uses of `%` from interfering with each other? I can think of four strategies.

Load the Lua code in such a way that it's not processed by LaTeX inappropriately.

- Place the Lua code in an external file (generally with extension `.lua`, e.g., `file.lua`) and load the code into LuaTeX with a `\directlua{dofile("file.lua")}` instruction.
- In your main tex file, load the [luacode](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luacode) package, which provides environments called `luacode` and `luacode*`, and place your Lua code in either a `luacode` or a `luacode*` environment.

Instead of `\directlua`, use an instruction which can handle `\%` as a substitute for `%` while executing Lua code.

- Load the `luacode` package, which provides the macro `\luaexec` (to be used instead of `\directlua`), and "escape" all instances of `%` with a backslash, i.e., rewrite them as `\%`. E.g.,

  ```
  \luaexec{tex.sprint(string.format('\%.3f', math.pi))}
  ```

Define a macro called, say, `\percentchar` which expands to `%` without this character being interpreted by TeX as a comment character. This allows continued use of `\directlua`.  (Many thanks to Joseph Wright for providing this suggestion and to @egreg for providing a pointer to an even more parsimonious definition of `\percentchar`!)

- The fourth method works by making the `%` character non-special to TeX's eyes. Place the following instruction -- `\@percentchar` is defined by the LaTeX "kernel"; it outputs a catcode-12 ("other") form of `%` -- in the preamble:

  ```
  \makeatletter\let\percentchar\@percentchar\makeatother
  %% or: \begingroup\catcode`\%=12\relax\gdef\percentchar{%}\endgroup
  ```

  Then, execute this instruction in the body of the document:

  ```
  \directlua{tex.sprint(string.format('\percentchar.3f', math.pi))}
  ```

  Recall that `\directlua` is expandable, i.e., it'll expand `\percentchar` to `%`, which is the character Lua needs to see in the `string.format` function. And, because this form of `%` has been given catcode 12 ("other"), it won't be misinterpreted as a comment character by LaTeX -- and all is well. :-)

  While this fourth approach may seem a bit cumbersome at first, it enjoys the undeniable virtue of being implementable without having to load any packages (such as the `luacode` package) or having to place the Lua code in an external file.

---

Which of these four methods one should use depends crucially on what one needs to accomplish when making a Lua call. If it's just a single instance of a simple instruction, the third and fourth methods may be easiest. If the Lua code is long and complex, the first and second methods are almost certainly to be preferred.

The first three possibilities are illustrated in the following example.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
%% create an external file, to store Lua code
\begin{filecontents*}{aux.lua}
function printpi (n) -- n: number of decimal digits to be shown
  tex.sprint ( string.format ( '%.'..n..'f' , math.pi ))
end
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\directlua{ dofile ( "aux.lua" ) } % load Lua code from external file

\usepackage{luacode} % load 'luacode' package
\begin{luacode}
function pi3() -- this function doesn't take an argument
  tex.sprint ( string.format ( '%.3f' , math.pi ) )
end
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
$\pi \approx \directlua{printpi(3)}$

$\pi \approx \directlua{pi3()}$

$\pi \approx \luaexec{tex.sprint(string.format('\%.3f', math.pi))}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps add that you could simply define appropriate macros and use in `\directlua`, _e.g._ ``\begingroup\catcode`\%=12\relax\gdef\percentchar{%}\endgroup`` then `\directlua{tex.sprint(string.format('\percentchar.3f', math.pi))}`

Comment: @JosephWright - Many thanks for this suggestion. I've updated my answer to incorporate it.

Comment: @JosephWright Or, more simply, `\makeatletter\let\percentchar\@percentchar\makeatother`

Comment: @egreg - Excellent suggestion! :-) I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Mico, thank you ever so much to you and to egreg and JosephWright. Apparently, the use of the filename "aux.lua" in
\begin{filecontents*}{aux.lua}  gives rise to problems, at least with MIKTEK (lualatex.log):

FATAL lualatex - No such file or directory: path="./aux.lua.tex"
FATAL lualatex - Info: path="./aux.lua.tex"
FATAL lualatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\File\win\winFile.cpp
FATAL lualatex - Line: 561
INFO  lualatex - finishing with exit code 1

if you use any other name, such "myfileLua.lua", everything is fine. Thanks again for your help!!!

Comment: @ANavarro - If MikTeX is looking for `aux.lua.tex`, something has gone very wrong. It should be looking for `aux.lua` -- note: no .tex extension. Interesting that some other file name, e.g., `myfile.lua`, does work. No idea why. (I use MacTeX, not MikTeX.)

Answer (score 3):

Here is another idea. Simply round of `math.pi` and show the result. Lua does not have a function that rounds up to `n` decimal places, but it is relatively simply to create one. The code below is in ConTeXt, but should be straight forward to translate to LaTeX as well:

```
\startluacode
  local floor, ceil = math.floor, math.ceil

  math.Round = function(x, n)
      local factor = math.pow(10, n or 0)
      local y = x * factor
      if x >= 0 then 
          y = floor(y + 0.5) 
      else
          y = ceil(y - 0.5)
      end

      return y / factor
  end
\stopluacode

\starttext
$π \approx \ctxlua{context(math.Round(math.pi, 3))}$
\stoptext
```

Answer (score 3):

What we can do in OpTeX:

```
$\pi \approx \directlua{tex.sprint(string.format('\%.3f', math.pi))}$
\bye
```