# Formatted date via directlua

Tags: luatex, catcodes, date

I would like to get today's date formatted using `\directlua`. The `%` signs seem to be a problem. And I don't know how to get it to work.

Both attempts in the following example throw errors:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Today: \directlua{tex.print(os.date("%d.%m.%y"))}
Today: \directlua{tex.print(os.date("\%d.\%m.\%y"))}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See also [problem with string.format, \directlua and tex.sprint](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/436979/5001).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several possible solutions. The two simplest ones I can think of are

- Define the macro `\percentchar` as follows:

  ```
  \makeatletter\let\percentchar\@percentchar\makeatother
  ```

  and use it in lieu of `%` in the argument of `\directlua`:

  ```
  Today: \directlua{tex.print(os.date("\percentchar d.\percentchar m.\percentchar y"))}
  ```

  Of course, you're free to come up with a snappier name than `\percentchar` for this macro.
- Load the `luacode` package and (a) use its `\luaexec` macro instead of `\directlua` and (b) change all instances of `%` in the argument of `\luaexec` to `\%`:

  ```
  Today: \luaexec{tex.print(os.date("\%d.\%m.\%y"))}
  ```

  As you can probably guess, one of purposes of `\luaexec` is to simplify the use of TeX-special characters such as `%` and `#` while still allowing expansion of (La)TeX macros.

---

A full MWE; no screenshot necessary, I think:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for '\luaexec' macro
\makeatletter\let\percentchar\@percentchar\makeatother
\begin{document}
Today: \directlua{tex.sprint(os.date("\percentchar d.\percentchar m.\percentchar y"))},
Today: \luaexec{tex.sprint(os.date("\%d.\%m.\%y"))}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Fantastic and enlightening answer. – Thanks!