# siunitx table, formatting \directlua{} ouput

Tags: tables, luatex, siunitx, directlua

I have a table with values calculated with `\directlua{}`.
They are formatted with `siunitx` columns.

I want to turn some values bold or change their color.

It appears that the output of `\directlua{}` macros are formatted like raw text, not as the `siunitx S` column should do.

MWE:

```
% Latex program : luaLatex
\documentclass{article}

% *** Fonts ***
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Tex Gyre Schola}[Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}]
% *** Tabular figures ***
\newfontfamily\TLFfont{Tex Gyre Schola}[Numbers={Monospaced,Lining}]

% *** siunitx ***
\usepackage{siunitx}
% french typesetting, 3-figures blocks
   \sisetup{locale=FR,group-minimum-digits=4}
% font detection
   \sisetup{detect-all}

% *** Lua percent sign ***
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436979/problem-with-string-format-directlua-and-tex-sprint
\makeatletter
   \let\luaPercent\@percentchar
\makeatother
% *** Rounding value ***
\newcommand*{\roundingValue}{2}
% ***

\usepackage{xcolor}

% *** Tabular bold / siunitx ***
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66253/siunitx-bold-single-numeric-cells
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\bfseries


\begin{document}

\sisetup{mode=text,text-rm=\TLFfont,unit-mode=text}
\begin{tabular}{lSSr}
      &   {raw text value} &   {directlua value} &    \\
   basic text &   1231.45 &   \directlua{n=1231.45 tex.print(string.format("\luaPercent.\roundingValue f",n))} &   right \\
   itshape &   \itshape 1231.45 &   \itshape \directlua{n=1231.45 tex.print(string.format("\luaPercent.\roundingValue f",n))} &   wrong \\
   bfseries &   \bfseries 1231.45 &   \bfseries \directlua{n=1231.45 tex.print(string.format("\luaPercent.\roundingValue f",n))} &   wrong \\
   color &   \color{red}1231.45 &   \color{red}\directlua{n=1231.45 tex.print(string.format("\luaPercent.\roundingValue f",n))} &   wrong \\
   tex.sprint &   &   \color{red}\directlua{n=1231.45 tex.sprint(string.format("\luaPercent.\roundingValue f",n))} &   wrong \\
   tex.cprint 11 &   &   \color{red}\directlua{n=1231.45 tex.cprint(11, string.format("\luaPercent.\roundingValue f",n))} &   wrong \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I use an old style numbers font on purpose, to enhance the differences:

[image]
<sub>(source: [toile-libre.org](https://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1585079718.png))</sub>

The only right formatted text is when no modifier is applied.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue isn't directly related to `\directlua`, the same thing happens if you replace `\directlua{...}` with a macro which expands to a number. In both cases, siunitx has to look at the value after it has been expanded by TeX into the actual number, but the expansion code in siunitx is interrupted by the unexpandable commands `\color`, `\itshape` etc.
You can avoid this by manually by manually adding (lots of `\expandafter`s or) `\expanded`, to ensure that the value is fully expanded before siunitx sees the unexpandable command:

```
% Latex program : luaLatex
\documentclass{article}

% *** Fonts ***
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Tex Gyre Schola}[Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}]
% *** Tabular figures ***
\newfontfamily\TLFfont{Tex Gyre Schola}[Numbers={Monospaced,Lining}]

% *** siunitx ***
\usepackage{siunitx}
% french typesetting, 3-figures blocks
   \sisetup{locale=FR,group-minimum-digits=4}
% font detection
   \sisetup{detect-all}

% *** Lua percent sign ***
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436979/problem-with-string-format-directlua-and-tex-sprint
\makeatletter
   \let\luaPercent\@percentchar
\makeatother
% *** Rounding value ***
\newcommand*{\roundingValue}{2}
% ***

\usepackage{xcolor}

% *** Tabular bold / siunitx ***
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66253/siunitx-bold-single-numeric-cells
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\bfseries


\begin{document}

\sisetup{mode=text,text-rm=\TLFfont,unit-mode=text}
\begin{tabular}{lSSr}
      &   {raw text value} &   {directlua value} &    \\
   basic text &   1231.45 &   \directlua{n=1231.45 tex.print(string.format("\luaPercent.\roundingValue f",n))} &   right \\
   itshape &   \itshape 1231.45 &   \expanded{\noexpand\itshape \directlua{n=1231.45 tex.print(string.format("\luaPercent.\roundingValue f",n))}} &   right \\
   bfseries &   \bfseries 1231.45 &   \expanded{\noexpand\bfseries \directlua{n=1231.45 tex.print(string.format("\luaPercent.\roundingValue f",n))}} &   right \\
   color &   \color{red}1231.45 &   \expanded{\noexpand\color{red}\directlua{n=1231.45 tex.print(string.format("\luaPercent.\roundingValue f",n))}} &   right \\
   tex.sprint &   &   \expanded{\noexpand\color{red}\directlua{n=1231.45 tex.sprint(string.format("\luaPercent.\roundingValue f",n))}} &   right \\
   tex.cprint 11 &   &   \expanded{\noexpand\color{red}\directlua{n=1231.45 tex.cprint(11, string.format("\luaPercent.\roundingValue f",n))}} &   wrong \\
   tex.cprint 12 &   &   \expanded{\noexpand\color{red}\directlua{n=1231.45 tex.cprint(12, string.format("\luaPercent.\roundingValue f",n))}} &   right \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

(Alternatively, the issue could also be fixed by printing `\color` or the font command through `tex.print` in the `\directlua` call instead of issuing them separately)
[image]