# lua code inside directlua throws an invalid escape sequence error

Tags: luatex, input, automation

I'm trying to make use of `lualatex` to automate generation of some part of a pdf. The directory tree for my minimal working example looks like the following:

```
│   lua_escaping_issue.tex
│
└───a_folder
        first_file.tex
        fourth_file.tex
        second_file.tex
        third_file.tex
```

- `a_folder/first_file.tex` contains the text "Hello"
- `a_folder/second_file` contains the text "World"
- `a_folder/third_file` contains the text "!. How are"
- `a_folder/fourth_file` contains the text "you?"

Using `lua`, I'd like to generate the text "HelloWorld!.How areyou?". So I wrote `lua_escaping_issue.tex` which contains the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


        \directlua
            {
                require 'lfs'
                
                for file in lfs.dir("a\_folder") do
                    if file ~= "." and file ~= ".." then
                        tex.print("\\input\{" .. "a\_folder/" .. file .. "\}")
                    end 
                end
            }

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately when I compile with `latexmk -lualatex lua_escaping_issue.tex` I get an error:

> [\directlua]:1: invalid escape sequence near '"a\p'

I believe the idea of `\directlua` is that everything will be expanded, therefore commands susceptible to be recognized by LaTeX should be escaped. I've already done this, and also tested my file in pure `lua`  and it seems to work. So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: See [luatex - problem with string.format, \directlua and tex.sprint - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436979/problem-with-string-format-directlua-and-tex-sprint)

Comment: (not exactly the same character, but same strategy)

Comment: [pdftex] tag is wrong though.

Comment: @user202729 Ok... so I guess based on the answer to that question the short answer is "use the luacode package"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to prevent `\\`  and `~` from expanding. prefixing them wih `\`  does not do that:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \directlua{
% no   require 'lfs'
                
        for file in lfs.dir("a_folder") do
           if file \string~= "." and file \string~= ".." then
              tex.sprint( "\string\\input{a_folder/" .. file .. "}" )
           end 
        end

    }   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes things a little clearer. I'm a bit surprised that `require`ing `lfs` is not needed. I thought that wasn't part of the standard library...

Comment: @user32882 the standard Lua libs are not in luatex's default paths, but lfs is compiled in (see `texdoc luatex`)