# [\directlua]:1: invalid escape sequence - a no \string solution please

Tags: pgfkeys, directlua

I have to pass different strings from latex to lua as arguments.
I have a solution for an argument in a command, but in case of pgf keys, it seems not working. Use \string is not suitable, if it looks like in this answer [lua code inside directlua throws an invalid escape sequence error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/640858/lua-code-inside-directlua-throws-an-invalid-escape-sequence-error), because it's not user friendly in pgfkeys argument

Any idea to avoid this problem

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\Contraintes}[1]{%
    \directlua{ contraintes = "\unexpanded{#1}" }
}


\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{/Baq/.cd ,
            contraintes/.store in = \contraintes,
            contraintes = { 3 ~= 1 }
}

\begin{frame}

% this is working
%\Contraintes{ 2~=1 }


% alternatively this is not working
\directlua{
    contraintes = "\unexpanded{\contraintes}"
}

\directlua{
    tex.print ( contraintes )
}


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\unexpanded\expandafter{\contraintes}"`

Comment: Works fine, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

`\unexpanded\expandafter{\contraintes}`

or perhaps better

`\detokenize\expandafter{\contraintes}`