# Can't use percent sign in \directlua

Tags: luatex, lua, percent-sign

while the following works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}
\directlua{token.set_macro("prjdatetime", os.date())}
\end{document}
```

I get in trouble when I want to customize the date- and timeformat:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}
\directlua{token.set_macro("prjdatetime", os.date("\%Y"))}
\end{document}
```

The error is:

```
(./test.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)[\dir
ectlua]:1: invalid escape sequence near '"\%'.
l.4 ...ken.set_macro("prjdatetime", os.date("\%Y"))}
```

The command to compile I'am using is:

```
lualatex --jobname=test escape.tex
```

The version:

```
lualatex --version
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.17.0 (TeX Live 2023)
Development id: 7581
```

Please help! Thx!

Comment: [Mico's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/436981/119) provides 4 strategies to handle the unfortunate interaction between how the percent symbol is treated in TeX and in Lua.

Answer (score 1):

Thx to Willie Wongs tip I used following solution:

```
\makeatletter\let\percentchar\@percentchar\makeatother
\directlua{token.set_macro("prjdatetime", os.date("\percentchar c \percentchar Z"))}
```